# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-EC5FHz/tornado/

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, ipywidgets

I am trying to install ipywidgets  from here [https://pypi.org/project/ipywidgets/] but output:

```
Cannot uninstall 'ipython'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I get some solution here [[PIP: "Cannot uninstall 'ipython'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421287/pip-cannot-uninstall-ipython-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project-and-thus-w])
I used:

```
sudo pip install ipywidgets --ignore-installed -U ipython
```

unfortunately, I got another issue:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-J1GUY8/tornado/
```

I tried to fix it from here [[Import Error - Tornado requires an updated SSL module on ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000512/import-error-tornado-requires-an-updated-ssl-module-on-ubuntu-14-04]), but I can't

please help me or any suggestion

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix it with me

step 1: I update python 2.7.6 to 2.7.12

step 2: `sudo pip install ipywidgets`

step 3: install jupter from here [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847263/install-jupyter-notebook-for-python-2-7/847266)

using these

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python-pip python-dev
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
sudo apt-get -y install ipython ipython-notebook
sudo -H pip install jupyter
```